# Is there a way to pass the 'bazel run' result file to the next rule file in bazel?

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules, bazel-aspect

I created a first rule file to geneate a scirpt using the `ctx.actions.expand_template` and ran it. and I wanted that pass the result of `bazel run` with first rule to the next 2nd rule file as a resource. But, I could't get the result which is generated by `bazel run` 1st rule in the 2nd rule.
It does not mean the script created by the first rule, but the file created when the script is executed.

Below example is what I tested.

This is bazel rule file

```
def _1st_rule_impl(ctx):

...

    out = ctx.outputs.executable
    template = ctx.file.my_template

    ctx.actions.expand_template(
        output = out,
        template = template,
        substitutions = {
            "{ARG1}: ctx.attr.my_file_name,
            "{ARG2}: ctx.attr.my_file_content,
        }

    return [
        DefaultInfo(
            files = depset([out]),
            runfiles = ctx.runfiles(files = [out])
        )
    ]

1st_rule = rule(
    implementation = _1st_rule_impl,
    attrs = {
        "my_template":attr.label(
            allow_single_file = True,
            default = Label("@my_test//my_rules:my_script.sh.template"),
        ),
        "my_file_name": attr.string(
            default = "myfile.txt",
        ),
        "my_file_content": attr.string(
            default = "hello world",
        ),
    },
    executable = True,
)

def _2nd_rule_impl(ctx):

...

    for dep in ctx.attr.deps:
        //
        // HOW CAN I GET THE RESULT OF `bazel run` THE '1st_rule'?
        // I WANT TO GET THE `myfile.txt` WHICH IS GENERATED BY '1st_rule'
        //

    return [
        DefaultInfo(
            files = depset([out]),
            runfiles = ctx.runfiles(files = [out]),
        )
    ]

2nd_rule = rule(
    implementation = _2nd_rule_impl,
    attrs = {
        "dep":attr.label_list(
            mandatory= True,
        ),
        ...
    },
    executable = True,
)
```

This is BUILD file

```
1st_rule(
    name = "my_1st_rule",
    my_file_name = "myfile.txt",
    my_file_content = "hello world",
)


2nd_rule(
    name = "my_2nd_rule",
    dep = [
        ":my_1st_rule",
    ],
)
```

This is template shell script

```
...
function create_file() {
    echo "{ARG2}" > "{ARG1}"
}
...
```

I tested with the example described above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to access the outputs of dependencies. Perhaps, the simplest is [`ctx.files`](https://bazel.build/rules/lib/ctx#files). For example, `print(ctx.files.dep)` in `_2nd_rule_impl` should show the output of `my_1st_rule` when `my_2nd_rule` is analyzed.

Comment: In this case, What I want to get object is not `my_1st_rule` script but `myfile.txt` which is generated by `my_1st_rule` file.

Comment: Then `my_1st_rule` needs to pass that file upwards, possibly with a [custom provider](https://bazel.build/extending/rules#providers)?

Comment: I tried to do that using `ctx.actions.run`. I applied to the `my_1st_rule`. This has `output` attribute so that add `output` to the `DefaultInfo.files` and then `my_2nd_rule` refer it. 

I think this is the solution for this issue.
Thank you for your help!